# SQL replace values in selection many columns

Tags: sql

I have two tables:

```
Table Users

UserId     Name
1          John
2          Alice
3          Tom
4          Charles
....
23120      Bob
```

and

```
Table Clients

Id        Name1   Name2    Name3  .... Name2345
1           1       3        450           4
2           2       17       33            1
...
15302920    44      231      5             7
```

I would like to make a SQL query where for

```
Clients.Id = 1
```

the results are like:

```
Id     Name1   Name2    Name3  ...  Name2345
1      John     Tom     Bill        Charles
```

My clients table has thousands of columns and I try to find a way to replace the values in all columns of the selected results (except the ID column) without thousands of joins.

I know that I can use a query of the following type (but I would like to avoid thousands of joins):

```
SELECT  a.ID,
    b.name name1,
    c.name name2,
    d.name name3
FROM    clients a
    INNER JOIN users b
        ON a.name1 = b.userID
    INNER JOIN users c
        ON a.name2 = c.userID
    INNER JOIN users d
        ON a.name3 = d.userID
WHERE   a.ID = 1
```

**In addtion:**

- I can't change the data/structure of the "Clients" table but I can change the "Users" table as necessary.
- I can't duplicate the "Clients" table as well since it very large and changes rapidly.
- The "Clients" table has thousands of columns and millions of rows, but the selected part is always a small enough subset of the table.

Is it possible?

Comment: Putting link will not make us understand what u want.. please expain with each detail clearly and specifically

Comment: I edited the question in order to make it clearer. I hope it's better.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple query to achieve this since SQL is fundamentally flexible in rows (vertically) and rigid in columns.  This is the closest I came up with:

```
select c.id, 
   (select name from dbo.users where UserId = c.name1),
   (select name from dbo.users where UserId = c.name2),
   (select name from dbo.users where UserId = c.name3),
   (select name from dbo.users where UserId = c.name4)
from clients c
```